# How to use okhttp3 for airflow experimental api in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, airflow, okhttp

I need to transform this command to okhttp request (value of the `conf` key must be a string)

```
curl -X POST \   http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs \   -d '{"conf":"{\"key\":\"value\"}"}'
```

Response of this code

> ```
> val conf = "'{\"conf\":\"{\\\"key\\\":\\\"$value\\\"}\"}'"
>         val body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), conf)
>         val request = Request.Builder()
>                 .url(url)
>                 .post(body)
>                 .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
>                 .build()
> ```

returns

> 400 Bad
>
> Request
>
> ## Bad Request
>
> The browser (or proxy) sent a
> request that this server could not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason may be in malformed JSON. Try assigning `conf` variable using Kotlin's raw strings:

```
val conf = """{"conf":"{\"key\":\"$value\"}"}"""
```